# USB-Speakers goes to sleep, causing a delay everytime a sound/notification is played

Tags: usb, audio, windows-11, speakers

I bought a USB speaker. That is a **speaker with only one USB connector. No 3.5mm.**

The problem is that for normal desktop use, where I don't have any background music playing, the plings and plongs for notifications are cut off because of a delay with starting the speaker?

It seems, everytime the sound in windows stops, the speaker go into some kind of power saving. So the next time a sound is played, it takes at least 0.5 seconds to power on before it starts to play a sound. That causes all notification sounds to be cut off - eg. it only plays the last half of the sound.

Anyone know of a solution to this? I doubt this is speaker specific (the speaker literally does not have any buttons or settings), but rather a Windows issue in how it handles USB-sound.

In Audio settings in Windows, when I click the Test button to click the test sound, I can see visually it starting to play it, but the speaker actually only starts playing the last second or so. In other words there's like 2 seconds of the test sound that is not played.
For some reason, the reaction is faster when I click the sound icon in status bar. Here it only skips the first 0.5 seconds before the sound can be heard.

Comment: What you can try is open a wave editor, such as audacity, create a new file that is empty, and press play so it loops. See if that solves your issue. In theory, it should not work. If so, that means the speaker itself is the issue indeed. If this works, then its on windows, either a driver or something in between. This issue is also a known issue if you RDP into another computer.

Comment: Check for and disable any power saving feature associated with that USB device in Device Manager.

Comment: @LPChip I'm sure playing white noise will keep it alive, but it's not really a viable solution, since I don't Windows will go to sleep if sound is played, and of course I need to manually start this every time I start the PC.

Comment: @ChanganAuto -  I already checked, that device does not have a tab for power managment :-/

Comment: I did not suggest this as a permanent solution. This is a test. Also, don't play white noise, play nothing, aka a silent waveform. For windows to play a silent waveform, it will have to open the device driver. While the silent waveform plays on loop, wait a bit, then play something else and see if it works as expected or not. This will tell you if the speaker is at fault or if its windows. Once you know for sure, 100% then you can look into your options. If its the speaker, and it has no options, consider replacing it. If its windows, then you can probably fix it.